# K-nearest neighbours on PCA results (python)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, knn

I work with python and some images of tables (taken from above). My aim is to classify these tables according to shape (square, rectangular, round) by analysing the table images with PCA and then use these results as an input to a k-nearest neighbours classifier.

My source code is the following:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn import neighbors


data = []
labels = []
# Read images from file
for filename in glob('Tables/*.jpg'):

    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width = img.shape[:2]
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    if height == 1125 and width == 2000:

        # Create the data list by reshaping an image from matrix to vector
        img = np.reshape(img, (1, 1125 * 2000))
        img = img[0]
        data.append(img)

        # Create the labels list
        if filename[11] == 'S':
            labels.append('Square')
        elif filename[12] == 'o':
            labels.append('Round')
        elif filename[12] == 'e':
            labels.append('Rectangular')


train_img, test_img, train_lbl, test_lbl = train_test_split( data, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

# Fit on training set only.
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(train_img)

# Apply transform to both the training set and the test set
train_img = scaler.transform(train_img)
test_img = scaler.transform(test_img)

# Make an instance of the pca model
pca = PCA(0.95)
pca.fit(train_img)
print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)

# Transform images with pca model
train_img = pca.transform(train_img)
test_img = pca.transform(test_img)

# Make an instance of knn model
knn = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(train_img, train_lbl)

# Accuracy of knn test
accuracy = knn.score(test_img, test_lbl)
print(accuracy)
```

The output to `print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)` is:

```
[ 0.22406799  0.14130877  0.07979864  0.05853734  0.05434577  0.0488873
  0.04629602  0.04229425  0.03923615  0.03613698  0.03199812  0.02858658
  0.02564182  0.02347223  0.01883306  0.01648042  0.01575557  0.01376232
  0.01296937]
```

and the output to 'print(accuracy)' is:

```
0.666666666667
```

Are these reasonable results if you take into account that I am using only 30 table images in my dataset or am I missing something important?

In general, did I apply correctly the knn algorithm on the pca results?

Comment: Instead of StandardScaler, try Normalizer.

Comment: They are reasonable in so far that given a test set of less than 20 instances (you have 6), a single outlier changes the score by a bigger margin than one standard deviation. Meaning, your results are more influenced by chance than the quality of your ML algorithm

Comment: Thanks @VivekKumar for your response. I replaced the Standard Scaler with the Normalised exactly at the same lines of the source code and the final accuracy is exactly the same. I hope that I am not doing anything wrong...

Comment: Thanks @ArneRecknagel for your response. Yes, obviously with so small dataset chance matters more. In this sense my question was more if I apply correctly the knn algorithm on the pca results... (Am I using correctly the output of pca as an input to the knn algorithm? etc)

Comment: Yes, the other code looks correct. In nearest neighbor problems, normalizer works better than StandardScaler. If its not, then I suppose you need to increase the data size.

Comment: You can try downsizing the resolution of image before sending it to PCA. That will decrease your features and may help the knn.

Comment: Any reason why you want to use KNN as opposed to a CNN? Seems like when you collapse a matrix of an image to a vector, you lose the information from the extra dimension. Also, if you plan on scaling this up with more training samples, your KNN scorer/predictor will take longer to run.

Comment: Thank you @Scratch'N'Purr for your response. Yes, I am thinking about using a CNN finally but I want firstly test some more basic machine learning techniques such as the knn algorithm. However, keep in mind that in some machine learning research papers knn is preferred over can owing to a variety of reasons (needs less data and time to train etc)...

Comment: *KNN is preferred over CNNs owing to a variety of reason...

Comment: Hmm, this is an interesting idea about the resolution of images @VivekKumar. I wanted to ask someone about the role of the resolution of images in these cases. However, I am not yet sure if this will necessarily help the results of the knn....

Comment: @Universalis CNN will indeed take longer to train, but will take significantly less time when predicting. KNNs on the other hand will take longer to predict as training samples increase - the train phase technically happens during the predict phase due to the algorithm having to calculate distances between all the training samples with the predict samples.

Comment: Yes, for sure, you are right and this is why I said that I will resort to CNNs finally.